# assertEquals Vs assertTrue for boolean

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert, assertion

You can test objects `assertEquals(a,b)` and `assertTrue(a.equals(b))` or `assertTrue(a==b)` (for primitives). In this case of course `assertEquals(a,b)` is the only possible variant. It is null safe and more informative in case of test fault (you get exact fault not true or false).

### I have a next question.

What about situation when we have only Boolean value to test?

`assertEquals(true, a)` and `assertTrue(a)`

What the difference can be?

### I see the case when we check Boolean. Using assertTrue(a) is not null safe. And this is very important reason. In case of boolean don't see the difference.

Comment: `assertEquals` at a failure would also show the expected and wrong value. That actually is the reason it exists. Compare it with java `assert ...;`

Answer (score 3):

`assertEquals(a, b)` and `assertTrue(a.equals(b))` are not the same, since the former will return true if both are null, while the latter will throw a null pointer exception.

The idiomatic way of writing `assertTrue(a == b)` is `assertSame(a, b)`, if `a` and `b` are references. For primitives, use `assertEquals`.

`assertEquals(true, a)` and `assertTrue(a)` are semantically identical. It's just a matter of style. The former would be considered by many to be bad style, in the same as this would be.

```
if (isActive() == true) {
    doThing()
}
```